# Ionic - Angular : Fetching data using HttpClient

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I am trying to fetch data in ionic from a given URL using the below simple code, but when I try to log the data it gives me undefined, please help.

**getcategories.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
 export class GetcategoriesService {
  public categories: any;
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

    initialize(){
    this.getservices().then(data => this.categories = data);
  }
  getservices(){
      const   url = 'url goes here';
      return this.http.get(url).toPromise();
  }

}
```

**services.page.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {GetcategoriesService} from '../../services/getcategories.service';
import {HttpClientModule} from '@angular/common/http';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-services',
  templateUrl: './services.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./services.page.scss'],
})
export class ServicesPage implements OnInit {
public data: any ;
  constructor( private  getmycategories: GetcategoriesService) { }
  ngOnInit() {
    this.data = this.getmycategories.categories;
    console.log(this.getmycategories.categories);
    console.log(this.data);

  }
}
```

**app.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { RouteReuseStrategy } from '@angular/router';

import { IonicModule, IonicRouteStrategy } from '@ionic/angular';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen/ngx';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar/ngx';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import {HttpClient, HttpClientModule} from '@angular/common/http';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  entryComponents: [],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(),
    AppRoutingModule,
    HttpClientModule,
   ],
  providers: [
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    { provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: IonicRouteStrategy }
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

I have been trying to log the data on the console but it returns undefined, APIs are working fine and it's a simple .json collection without any parameter so please advise me if I am missing something and how I can fix it.

Comment: Be aware that issues like this are often not that the data doesn't ever arrive, but that it doesn't arrive by the time you are checking for it. Hence: `undefined` at the time of checking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please refer to the [Angular tutorial](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt6). The data can not be printed, as the HTTP call might not have finished yet.

To fix your issue I would recommend using `Observables` instead of `Promises`.

#### Service

```
constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

getservices() {
  const url = 'url goes here';
  return this.http.get(url);
}
```

#### Page

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.getmycategories.getservices().subscribe(response => {
    console.log(response);
  });
}
```